# Largest multiple of n lower than x

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Most pythonic way avoiding for loops to find the largest number multiple of `n` but lower than an upperbound `x`?

Practical example:

```
n = 48 
x = 2636
```

`48 * 54 = 2592` is the nearest.

I am doing a `for` loop till I don't go over `x` now

Comment: `n*floor(x/n)`, with your example x/n=54.91, so the multiple is 48*54

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is probably using `//`:

```
(x // n) * n
```

If the number has to be strictly less than `x`, use `x - 1` instead:

```
((x - 1) // n) * n
```

The expression `x // n` is the floor division of `x` by `n`, discarding any remainder.

Comment: This is the only answer that takes the (strictly) "lower than" requirement into account.

Comment: @RoryDaulton. But the requirement can be extrapolated to the others quite trivially.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the modulo operation

```
x-(x%n)
```

If the upper bound has to be strictly lower than x use

```
x - 1 -((x-1) % n)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the operation is called modulo, not module: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=modulo#binary-arithmetic-operations (+1 BTW).

Answer (score 2):

This works too:

```
print(x - (x%n))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way I could think of would be for either python 2 or 3:

```
>>> (x // n) * n
```